# How do you perform Active Directory search with partial SID?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sid

Can you search for users with a partial SID?

```
get-aduser -ldapfilter "(objectSID=S-X-X-XX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXX-*)" -server YOURDOMAINNAME
```

Although my sample is PowerShell, I'm open to language agnostic answers

Answer (score 1):

No, the AD LDAP handler will not do a partial search on objectSID.  You wouldn't even expect it if it didn't handle other attribute types with octet string syntax, like `(objectGUID=\0c\9d\68\d9*)`. Equality match is possible though.